# "Error running javac compiler" when trying to compile code with Ant

Tags: java, linux, ant

I am trying to compile some Java code from a public GitHub repository that uses Ant. Working from the command line in Linux Mint, I'm getting

```
BUILD FAILED /mydir/biosim-develop/build.xml:90: Error running javac
compile
```

(/mydir is an abbreviation for a rather lengthy path.)

`$JAVA_HOME` is set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64.

I have Ant 1.10.7. The relevant part of the build.xml file reads:

```
<target name="compile-stubs" depends="init-build,init-tmp"
    description="compiles the IDL stubs">
    <echo message="Compiling stubs" />
    <javac target="1.8" source="1.8" srcdir="${stubsDir}" destdir="${buildDir}" fork="yes"
        memoryMaximumSize="256m" nowarn="yes" debug="on" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath refid="biosim.lib.build.path"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

Do I need to install a different version of Java or Ant? Can I just change the 1.8 to 1.11? Or is the problem something else?

Comment: Have you installed a JDK (with the `javac` tools) or just a JRE?  Look in the  "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin" directory.  Is `javac` there?  (You should be able to use a Java 11 `javac` to compile for a Java 8 target platform. At least, it works for me.)

Comment: what does `which javac` say? What happens if you type `javac -version`?

Comment: There's apparently no ```javac```. That would certainly do it!

Comment: I installed a JDK and it works now. The prior questions I looked at only talked about checking the Java path.

Comment: @tgdavies - That would be a clue ... but `which javac` tells you what is on `PATH` and Ant will be using `JAVA_HOME`.   So looking in the `$JAVA_HOME/bin` is more definitive ...